# How do I use the global variable in a snackbar?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I want to use the variable here:

```
     ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text(
//here
'Minimum order amount is' '${PriceConverter.convertPrice(context, Provider.of<SplashProvider>(context, listen: false).configModel
         .minimumOrderValue)}, //here you have ${PriceConverter.convertPrice(context, _itemPrice)}//here in your cart, please add more item.',
       ), backgroundColor: Colors.red));
```

Like i use the button:

```
CustomButton(btnTxt: getTranslated('place_order', context),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 Container(
                width: 500,
                height: 140,
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(Dimensions.PADDING_SIZE_SMALL),
                child: CustomButton(btnTxt: getTranslated('place_order', context), onTap: () {
                  if(_itemPrice < Provider.of<SplashProvider>(context, listen: false).configModel.minimumOrderValue) {
                    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text(
                      '${getTranslated('minimum_order_amount_is', context)} ${PriceConverter.convertPrice(context, Provider.of<SplashProvider>(context, listen: false).configModel
                          .minimumOrderValue)}, ${getTranslated('you_have', context)} ${PriceConverter.convertPrice(context, _itemPrice)} ${getTranslated('in_your_have_more', context)}',
                    ), backgroundColor: Colors.red));
                  } else {
                    Navigator.pushNamed(context, Routes.getCheckoutRoute(_total, 'cart', Provider.of<OrderProvider>(context, listen: false).orderType));
                  }
                    }),
          ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
     ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text(
'Minimum order amount is ${PriceConverter.convertPrice(context, Provider.of<SplashProvider>(context, listen: false).configModel
         .minimumOrderValue)}, ${PriceConverter.convertPrice(context, _itemPrice)}',
       ), backgroundColor: Colors.red));
```

Comment: getTranslated i want add this class. Text(getTranslated
('Minimum order amount')

Comment: what is the return of ```getTranslated```?

Comment: String getTranslated(String key, BuildContext context) {
  return AppLocalization.of(context).translate(key);
}